Print API objects/ Payload received via POST/GET on response with asyncio
I want to print out every API object I receive on an event or the whole payload respectively (POST/GET).
The code works and looks like below
Code:
async def main():
    async with client_session() as session:
        client = Client(session)
        await client.start()

asyncio.run(main())

The client_session() is just a function which returns an asyncio ClientSession() object
Solved:
Due to a moderator has closed this thread, I will post the solution I have found here.
Example:
async with session.get('https://api.github.com/events') as resp:
    print(resp.status)
    print(await resp.text())

Source: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html

I'm not sure what your question is...

I want to print out the payload the client receives on an event

Without knowing what API is this, we can't guess how to print, or even get, the payload. Isn't  print(client) sufficient?

Thank you for your help.
Unfortunately it does't work.
Isn't there a native method which asyncio serves to fetch all incoming payload?

So when you say "the code works" in the question, you really mean it does not work! Please edit your question to make things clearer.

The code does work. The Client can initiate a session and the specified methods do response on events.
I only need to see the payload for analysis purposes
